# Calling website with anchor breaks design

Tags: html, anchor, css-position

When I access the site with an anchor set (...#xxx) the image on top is shifted outside the viewport.

Normal behaviour: http://soc.org/index.php?id=4
Corrupted design: http://soc.org/index.php?id=4#c272

The top image is positioned absolute.
There are some blank lines directly after the google-analytics code. If I delete them, it works.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: That is really weird man... I can't figure it out. It's not just the image, btw... it's the entire '.page' wrapper element. In Firefox its appearing like it is set like '.page { top: -33px; }' even though it is clearly not. Hope some one else is better at CSS than me (quite likely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to see what's going on if you turn off the overflow:hidden on div.upperPage

You can see the anchor is causing the scroll on the contents of that, rather than on the page as a whole. However, I don't know of any specifications that state what elements should scroll to achieve the anchor requirement.

Comment: removing overflow:hidden fixed the problem for me. I don't know about similar problems, though